# Superscript Text in React Native

Tags: react-native

I would like to style text as superscript in React Native. How would this be accomplished? Is there a way to make use of the Javascript `sup()` string method to return a string as superscript within a `<Text>` object?

Answer (score 19):

I got this working for me using a view container and flex.

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'flex-start'}}>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 20, lineHeight: 30}}>10</Text>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 11, lineHeight: 18}}>am</Text>
</View>
```

Here is the link to this in action https://repl.it/Haap/0

Cheers!

Comment: I tried your solution but it gives me problems as described in the comments of one of the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536698/superscript-style-is-broken-in-my-react-native/49539524

Answer (score 4):

i just do this to achieve superscript in my case

```
 <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
  <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>e</Text>
  <Text style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>x</Text>
 </View>
```

Comment: The "x" needs to be positioned above the "e" though.

Answer (score 3):

Just use fontSize, lineHeight, textAlignVertical:

```
<Text style={{fontSize:20, lineHeight:22}}>
  foo
  <Text style={{fontSize:20 * 1.6, lineHeight:22 * 1.1, textAlignVertical: 'top'}}>
    bar
  </Text>
</Text>
```

Comment: I needed to fix because a special aspect ratio needs between the lineHeights

Comment: textAlignVertical is android only!

Answer (score 1):

Javascripts `sub()` function will only surround your text with `<sub></sub>` tags and they are recognized as text in RN. You would need to build your own function like:

```js
export default class Test extends Component {
    sub = (base, exponent) => {
        return <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <View style={{alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 13}}>{base}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{alignItems: 'flex-start'}}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 10}}>{exponent}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Text>{(() => 'hello'+'world'.sub())()}</Text>
                {(() => this.sub('hello','world'))()}
                {(() => this.sub('2','6'))()}
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

[image: Result in iOS Simulator]

Comment: Getting an error when I include this inside an existing `View`: "Views nested within a <Text> must have a width and height"

Comment: Also, from the React Native documentation, embedding a `View` within `Text` will work in iOS only. Not cross-platform.

Comment: That's right but if you are on android you could simply use `textAlignVertical: 'top'`

Comment: I think for now (if you want to use Text + nested exponents) you have to do really ugly mixtures of Views and Text Elements. Maybe take a look at [productpains](https://productpains.com/post/react-native/text-add-support-for-vertical-align-style-property) there is a voting system for future features. I added the link to [CSS vertical align property page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) with a reference to the sub/super properties.

Comment: On Android, I tried the `textAlignVertical: 'top'` property like so: `<Text>Productname<Text style={{fontSize: 9, textAlignVertical: 'top'}}>®</Text></Text>` to no avail. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The best method I found for this problem is not ideal, but it works cross-platform. The character I needed to superscript is the ® which some fonts have superscripted by default. So, I simply included a similar font family with the superscripted ® and it worked like magic.

Answer (score 0):

## Simple method for superscript Text in 2023

```
import React, { Text } from 'react-native'

type Props = {
  children: string
}

const SuperscriptText: React.FC<Props> = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <Text
      style={{
        fontSize: 8, // Should be smaller than the other text
        textAlignVertical: 'top',
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Text>
  )
}

export default SuperscriptText
```

Working on Android & iOs:

```
<Text>Default Text</Text>
<SuperscriptText>Hi</SuperscriptText>
<Text>Continue here</Text>
```

**Important note:** Currently this does not work when nesting text elements. See here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30375

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your super text inside of a normal test and all the style verticalAlign: 'super', to the super text.

```
  <Text style={{fontSize: 16}}>
   Main Text and{' '}
    <Text style={{fontSize: 10, lineHeight: 12, verticalAlign: 'super'}}>Superscript</Text>
  </Text>
```