# react-native: display superscript text in Text component

Tags: react-native, superscript

I have the following text:

```
<div>Answer the following <span class='title'>Question:</span><br> (a+b)<sup>2</sup>=?</div>
```

I want to do the following with this text:

- parse it tag by tag, so that I can render each of the tag in a custom way. I could, very well, achieve that using this library: https://github.com/Thomas101/react-native-fence-html.
- while parsing the superscript/subscript tags, render the content in proper fashion. This is where I'm stuck right now.

What I'm doing right now, is that I put the entire text (from start to end) in a Text component; and each span and br tags are also rendered as Text components nested within the parent Text component (the one for the div tag).
How do I render the superscript/subscript text?

Note: I did find a solution here: [Superscript Text in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002583/superscript-text-in-react-native)
But, creating a View inside a Text component needs the View to have fixed dimensions, and that is something not achievable.

Comment: If you found a solution would be nice to share it. Nested view is not supported in Android, isn't it?

Comment: @Max What I did end up doing was **render a webview with the html text** wherever required. In my application, there's not many instances where I need to do this, and hence, this works all right.
However, for future use-cases like these, I guess, an in-built feature of RN  to render html text in a Text/View component is required.

Answer (score -1):

One option would be to convert the HTML to Markdown first and then render the markdown. I believe for both of those actions there are libraries available.