# How can I wrap a TouchableOpacity around Text within Text?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to perform something like the following, which React Native does not like.

I want to wrap *clickable* text in a TouchableOpacity, and with its own styles.

By wrapping it in a parent `Text` component, all of the text sits perfectly side by side. However, I can't put a `TouchableOpacity` inside of a `Text` component.

```
<View>
  <Text>
    <Text>Hello my name is</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.openProfile}>
      <Text style={styles.clickable}>{ name }</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <Text>, I am currently working at </Text>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.openCompanyPage}>
      <Text style={styles.clickable}>{ company }</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </Text>
</View>
```

I get the error: `Views nested within a <Text> must have a width and height`. I am unable to set those measurements as I want them to be dynamic and be dependant on the content.

For example `name` could be John Smith or [Hubert Blaine Wolfe­schlegel­stein­hausen­berger­dorff Sr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubert_Blaine_Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff,_Sr.).

As per comment, I want to render portions of the text with custom styles. I can do that effortlessly by placing [Text within Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002583/superscript-text-in-react-native). Now I want to add a clickable area to those portions of text ("Dan", "Google"). But I cannot embed a TouchableOpacity inside of a Text element.

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me why do you want to do this? What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @BilalHussain just updated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include TouchableOpacity within Text ReactNative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52168451/how-to-include-touchableopacity-within-text-reactnative)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Dan. You need to achieve this by wrapping everything inside `<View>` tag and add style accordingly.

try this:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Hello my name is </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>Dan, </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>I am currently working at </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>Google</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
```

Let me know. Thanks

Ref for more style : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html

Comment: Works fantastically. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work if the text is wrapped, i.e. flows onto more than one line

Answer (score 28):

Actually the solution of Bilal Hussain did not work for me. I got an error saying `Nesting of <View> within <Text> is not supported on Android`.

What worked for me was the solution described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52168520/1175081). Just using `<Text>` elements only and applying a `onPress` property to them like so:

```js
<Text>
        Hello my name is
        <Text style={{color: 'red'}} onPress={function1}>Dan, </Text>
        I am currently working at
        <Text style={{color: 'red'}} onPress={function2}>Google</Text>
</Text>
```

Comment: Nesting of <View> within <Text> is supported on Android