# How to change text background and opacity on touch, not on press

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to replicate TouchableOpacity, but in a Text component, since when I use TouchableOpacity the text gets uncentered. How do I make it so when I touch the Text, not yet released it, the styles to change?

Followed this:
[How can I wrap a TouchableOpacity around Text within Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348514/how-can-i-wrap-a-touchableopacity-around-text-within-text)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TouchableOpacity onPressIn/onPressOut props (docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#onpressin)

If you nest the Touchable inside a Text tag, it will stay inline with the rest of your text.

```js
  <Text>Here is a <TouchableOpacity><Text style={{ color: '#beb' }}>link</Text></TouchableOpacity>. It doesn't disrupt the flow of the text</Text>
```

You could also use a Pressable, which has the same props, or accepts a callback as a child that provides a `pressed` argument:

```
<Pressable>
  {(pressed) => (
    <Text style={pressed ? styles.pressed : styles.unpressed>
    ...
```

Docs for Pressable are here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable

Comment: Yes, but TouchableOpacity creates its own view and dislodges the text from the main line. Is there a way to make the Text style change while being pressed without any new Views being added

Comment: If you nest the TouchableOpacity (or Pressable) inside a Text tag, it will stay in the same line as the rest of the text.  I'll update with an example.

Comment: You can't put text in a TouchableOpacity. If you add a TouchableOpacity you have to add another Text component inside and it dislodges the text

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Check this snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@256hz/text-link

Comment: Quite literally, the samo code, but my Text goes a bit higher than the normal text flow. Don't think that the issue would be from class and functional component. But I am doing the same thing and getting a different result. Also I am using tailwind for styles, but I couldn't imagine that being the problem either.

Comment: It works with built in components, so I would recommend using those or taking out elements until your problem is fixed.

Comment: Well is there a way to create a TouchableOpacity with a text? Like add a pressable prop of sort to it?

Comment: Text has an onPress prop, but not onPressIn - https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#onpress. It'll be easier if you're not fighting RN and use the builtin components though

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/31288/files/b7c5adf12cd6e4684b3dcdccdd23ac5a8c5ed126#diff-8854d86a25d1052c7f65f4d7235198297464645255149b9700171beb00ca67ec
doesn't this conclude that onPressIn and onPressOut are added to Text?

Comment: Oh yeah, looks like it!  As long as your RN version is new enough

Comment: @Abe this no longer works in 2024. Scanned your snack and got disrupted text. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: @NathanTew updated snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@256hz/text-link just using the Text component. Note you must have onPress defined for onPressIn/Out to work.

Comment: @Abe unfortunately, I also need the link to prevent a parent from registering the tap as well (it is in a message box in a chat which registers taps). The solution I found was to use `onStartShouldSetResponder`, but that prop is only available with a `View`, which causes the same problem as the `TouchableOpacity`...

Comment: sounds like a separate question...